# Simple Password Tester C#

Tags: c#, testing, passwords, .net-4.8

I'm tinkering with a very basic password tester. I'm trying to compare the input string with a given string of acceptable characters.

```cs
public static bool hasRequiredChar(string input)
{
    input = "input";
    string requiredChar = "abcde";

    foreach (var item in requiredChar)
    {
        if (input.Contains(item)) return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

If I only use System, I get the error message: "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'char' to 'string'". This refers to the string.Contains() method. Any ideas?

I know there are 1000 ways to write this differently but I don't want to use Regex, Linq or anything other than System.

Comment: There is no way the code above is giving you that error. `string` contains overloads for both `char` and `string` parameters.

Comment: Try it in DotNetFiddle yourself, this causes a compile time error.

Comment: Or perhaps you are using .NET Framework that doesn't have the `char` overload? You need to tell us more.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing to `string.Contains` a char, when in .NET Framework it  instead expects a string. To pass in the argument, simply cast it to a string first.

```
foreach (var item in requiredChar)
{
    if (input.Contains(item.ToString()) return true;
}
```

There are some other problems with your approach if you're trying to check if the string contains all required characters, but that's aside from your error.

Comment: Except that it does accept a `char` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=net-5.0#System_String_Contains_System_Char_

Comment: Yes, they may be using .NET Framework 4.x, see my comment on the question.

Comment: Precisely, why I suggested casting to string instead. No reason to be so blunt.

Comment: How exactly was I being blunt? I was just explaining things. And if you knew it was a .NET 4.x thing, you should have mentioned that in the answer.

Comment: Thanks, that did it. What other problems are you foreseeing?

Comment: If you're looking to check that your string contains *every* character in that string, then you'll want to return false if you *don't* find the character, and only return true at the very end. If you're just checking for one character then the code's fine :)